# Encoding and decoding in json

Tags: php

If a json data

```
{"inf": "Väri-väri"}
```

is saved like

```
{"inf": "Vu00e4ri-vu00e4ri"}
```

How to recover letters õ, ä, ö, ü, etc in whole json with php. utf8_decode, and utf8_encode i tried.
Thank you.

Comment: You say "saved". Where is it saved (file, DB, etc?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some flag for `jsong_encode` for get option : http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php try

```php
json_encode($myVar,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is not the JSON encoding in itself, but how you store the encoded JSON document. Note how the encoded JSON document actually **should** look like:

```
$a = ["inf" => "Väri-väri"];
echo json_encode($a) . "\n";
// prints: {"inf":"V\u00e4ri-v\u00e4ri"}
```

This is the expected behaviour in PHP and totally consistent with the JSON spec in [RFC-7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-8):

> Any character may be escaped.  If the character is in the Basic
> Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be
> represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed
> by the lowercase letter u, followed by four hexadecimal digits that
> encode the character's code point.  The hexadecimal letters A though
> F can be upper or lower case.  So, for example, a string containing
> only a single reverse solidus character may be represented as
> "\u005C".

However, you're losing the `\` characters at some point when storing the data. A wild guess is that you're storing these strings in a relational database using SQL and did not escape properly. The first thing I'd suggest is to investigate how you store your data and ensure that backslashes are properly escaped when storing these strings in a database. If stored correctly, [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) will easily decode the encoded characters back to regular unicode characters.

Alternatively, you can disable this behaviour by passing the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag into `json_encode`:

```
echo json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php). If you decode the json code, the letters will be recovered.